# Delphi - Saving TStringStream to SQL

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-xe2, stringstream

I am using Embarcadero Delphi XE2

I'm creating a fastreport (its not that important) and saving it to TStringStream

Next just for tests I output that TStringStream to file, and the PDF saves fine and opens fine. It weights about 40KB (less)

What I need to do next, is write this PDF (TStringStream) to SQL database through INSERT, the only thing I do to modify it is I replace all " with "" because its within " quotes, otherwise the SQL doesn't work.

The strange thing is, when I load the file from database, or even to SELECT length(attachment) where the attachment is PDF data saved earlier. When I do that, the size is more than 50KB (for some PDF's even about 70KB), and the PDF is whole blank.

I am forced to use a simple mysql unit for this project which doesn't allow some setParams or saving it through Blob object which I googled. So I need an answer concerning this simple method. Insert TStringStream to SQL database.

The database field is type MEDIUMBLOB

Thanks in advance!

Jack

Comment: Read a little about the BLOB data type.

Comment: If your field type is string(and you can't change it for whatever reason), then maybe saving as base64 encoded is an option.

Comment: fieldtype is MEDIUMBLOB but for whatever reason when I insert it into database the data grows by 25% and when I save it back from db the PDF (the data) is corrupted

Comment: Why do you store a binary in a string stream? If you want to store it as a (printable) string, better follow @Computer advice and convert it to base64!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by:

1. Export through frxPDFExport,
2. override its stream to TMemoryStream,
3. Converting the TMemoryStream to Hex String
4. and INSERTING it to sql as '0x'+converted_hex_string

Thanks for help anyway,
hope this answer helps with similar problem

Important:
it had to be TMemoryStream because of some strange ASCII chars in PDF, so when I exported it to TStringStream and then converted to hex, it came out corrupted.

You can look up on the net there's the function to convert byte array (TMemoryStream) to hexed string.

Jack.

Answer (score 3):

Define a blob field in your database, then you can use your DataSet component's `CreateBlobStream()` method to get a `TStream` object that you can use to read from, and write to, the blob field as needed.

You might even be able to eliminate the `TMemoryStream` completely, depending on how it is being used in the rest of your code.  For instance, if you are just saving the PDF to a temp `TMemoryStream` for the sole purpose of storing it in the database, then you can get rid of the `TMemoryStream` and have FastReport save the PDF directly to the blob field via the `TStream` that `CreateBlobStream()` returns.

Comment: The project I'm working on uses a simple mysql library for Delphi and all I can do is write an INSERT ... VALUES (stringStream.DataStream) the problem is I get a corrupted PDF when I read it from there, in php I would addslashes(stringSteam.DataStream) but here I dont know which characters I should escape

Comment: @Prozi - what mysql library are you using?

Comment: The header-comment says: MySQL Client API for Borland Delphi (version 4 and above)

Pascal Interface Unit for libmySQL.dll, the
Client Library for MySQL AB's SQL Database Server

This is a literal translation of relevant parts of MySQL AB's
C header files, mysql.h, mysql_com.h, and mysql_version.h

Comment: @Prozi Is your column a blob one? Does the library you use support parameters? You better edit your question to add that vital information, since you omit that, one thinks you're using DataSet descendants, which is the preferred way to go.

Comment: Using a parameterized SQL query is a good choice, yes. You can `INSERT INTO` a blob field using either `TParam.LoadFromStream(...)`, `TParam.SetBlobData(...)`, `TParam.AsBlob := ...`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the data type you are using.  As tvdien stated, take a look at blob fields for your storage if you haven't already.  With a blob field, loading to the database and saving back to a memory stream is easy.  To load to the database you would do this:

`TBlobField(MyQuery.FieldByName('MyName')).LoadFromStream(MyMemoryStream)`

and copying from the database back to the memory stream uses the `SaveToStream` in the TBlobField class.

Comment: Rather than accessing `TBlobField` directly, you should use the DataSet's `CreateBlobStream()` method instead, and then read/write your data from/to the returned `TStream` as needed.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau - How is the CreateBlobStream method better than recasting the field and loading from a memory stream?  From the documentation I can see, the blob stream created is more volatile than recasting and has to be recreated for every blob on every record.

Comment: `CreateBlobStream()` is the preferred method. It allows the DataSet to decide how best to access the field data by using optimized `TStream` implementations. If you look at the implementation of `TBlobField` in DB.pas, it uses `CreateBlobStream()` internally. But by using `TBlobField` directly like you are, your code has to know what `TBlobField` is and whether a field is a `TBlobField` or not so the type-cast will not fail, whereas you don't have to worry about that if you call `CreateBlobStream()` directly.

Comment: Also, by using `CreateBlobStream()` directly, you might be able to eliminate the `TMemoryStream`, depending on how it is being used. If you are just saving something to a temp `TMemoryStream` and then loading it into the blob field, you can get rid of the `TMemoryStream` and save your data directly to the blob field.

Comment: Ok, I can see your point, though the caveats still apply, and one has to be more careful with using CreateBlobStream directly.  I got used to working with datasets that had the fields defined in code, so we always knew about the blobfields anyway.  And with the OP stuffing a report into a stream, the CreateBlobStream could work alone just fine.  Two different implenetations, same result.

Comment: Different implementations for the same result, but one of them is abstract and extendable whereas the other one relies on a specific implementation detail, which is not a good way to write code. Just saying.

Comment: @Remy, you should post an answer using CreateBlobStream.

Comment: The project I'm working on uses a simple mysql library for Delphi and all I can do is write an INSERT ... VALUES (stringStream.DataStream) the problem is I get a corrupted PDF when I read it from there, in php I would addslashes(stringSteam.DataStream) but here I dont know which characters I should escape